# Хранение статуса 'прочитанная тема'

Tags: база-данных, php

Добрый день. Как лучше в базе данных хранить статусы прочитанных тем? Вот мой вариант. Хранение в базе данных:

```
|------------|------------|
|  topic_id  |  users_id  |
|------------|------------|
|  49        |  5,80,30   |
|------------|------------|
```

Распознавание:

```
...
$users = explode(",", $row['users_id']);
if(in_array(id_текущего_пользователя, $users))
{
   echo "Тема прочитана текущим пользователем";
}
```

Установка статуса:

```
...
$users = explode(",", $row['users_id']);
if(!in_array(id_текущего_пользователя, $users))
{
   $row['users_id'] += id_текущего_пользователя.",";
   $DB->exec("UPDATE `reads` SET `users_id`='".$row['users_id']."' WHERE `topic_id`=".id_топика);
}
```

---

Верно ли такое решение? Или же можно сделать проще?

Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы храните неправильно,

надо хранить topic_id int,user_id int (может с ключом (topic_id,user_id), чтобы узнать, что юзер прочитал топик достаточно сделать:

```
SELECT 1 FROM reads WHERE user_id=? AND topic_id=?;
```

чтобы найти темы прочитанные юзером

```
SELECT topic_id FROM reads WHERE user_id=?;
```

чтобы посмотреть какие юзеры прочитали тему

```
SELECT user_id FROM reads WHERE topic_id=?;
```

Comment: В таком случаи будет очень много записей в таблице. Или об этом можно не думать?

Comment: это лучше, чем множество длинных строк (если юзеров будет больше 1000, то вам вообще придется там text поле делать, со своими приколами), к тому-же 2й пример в идее с длинными строками будет весьма тормозным запросом. насчет общего ключа, это тот ещё вопрос, но индексы на user_id и topic_id нужно создать.